# Use google map API in a react babel component

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, babeljs

I currently try to use google map API with react js and babel. I don't want to use the existing react components (that are uncomplete).

The problem I encounter is that I can't load the google map object. Babel always show me a compilation error like this one :

```
error    'google' is not defined
```

Event if I load the google map script in my index :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" ></script>
```

I understand that babel doesn't load the google map library at compile time, but try to compile some code lines like this :

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')...
```

Is there someone who know how to handle this case ?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the google maps api npm module and import it into your relevent files. https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps

Comment: Yes ! That was unexpectedly easy !
Thank you !